# SQL SeErver : INSERT statement, calculate two column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, calc

I have three tables:

1. Voucher_Codes (Amount_Used)
2. Gift_Vouchers (Amount)
3. Order_Header (Order_Voucher_Amount)

I want to insert the data from column `Voucher_Codes` into `Order_Header`. But I need to do this calculation before I can merge the data:

3 = 2 - 1

How can I do this, and if possible can I do it then remove `Voucher_Codes` later without it affecting my data sets?

Comment: Using insert trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT (Voucher_Codes.Amount_Used - Gift_Vouchers.Amount) AS Order_Voucher_Amount
FROM Voucher_Codes
JOINT Gift_Vouchers ON Voucher_Codes.KEY = Gift_Vouchers.KEY)
FROM Order_Header
JOINT Voucher_Codes ON Voucher_Codes.KEY = Order_Header.KEY
```

Then you can insert the new data into this adjusted table.